# Mongodb query for upcoming dates in month/day timeframe

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How can I query a database of users with their birthdays stored as a Date for the users with upcoming birthdays?
For example if a user is stored as:
name : "John Doe"
birthday : `1980-06-30T00:00:00.000+00:00`
and their birthday is within a month, how do I retrieve it?

I have tried this in pymongo but it only returns people with their birthdays exactly today and one month from now.

```
find({
    "$and": [
        {"$and": [
            {"$expr": {"$gte": [{"$month": "$birthday"}, today.month]}},
            {"$expr": {"$gte": [{"$dayOfMonth": "$birthday"}, today.day]}}
        ]},
        {"$and": [
            {"$expr": {"$lte": [{"$month": "$birthday"}, one_month_from_today.month]}},
            {"$expr": {"$lte": [{"$dayOfMonth": "$birthday"}, one_month_from_today.day]}}
        ]}
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your filter like this:

```
find({
    "$or": [
        {"$and": [
            {"$expr": {"$eq": [{"$month": "$birthday"}, today.month]}},
            {"$expr": {"$gte": [{"$dayOfMonth": "$birthday"}, today.day]}}
        ]},
        {"$and": [
            {"$expr": {"$eq": [{"$month": "$birthday"}, one_month_from_today.month]}},
            {"$expr": {"$lte": [{"$dayOfMonth": "$birthday"}, one_month_from_today.day]}}
        ]}
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to make it so it found all days where `(month == today.month && day >= today.day) || (month == one_month_from_today.month && day <= one_month_from_today.day)`